# Is the prototype of scandir() broken?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, glibc, scandir

Referring to glibc function `scandir()` [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Scanning-Directory-Content):

The 3rd parameter to `scandir()` is a pointer to a function that takes a single parameter of type `const struct dirent*` - that function, if provided, selects which directory entries to include in the result.

=> Fine.

The 4th parameter to `scandir()` is a pointer to a function that takes two parameters of type `const struct dirent**` - that comparison function is used to sort the results.

=> Why is the type of these parameters not `const struct dirent*`, just as for the 3rd parameter? Why a double pointer?! And if someone finds a reason for the double pointer, why is the double pointer not declared `const`, like this: `const struct dirent*const*`? The comparison function is not supposed to change the order of the directory entries.

(Of course, you have to worry about the fourth parameter to `scandir()` only when you provide your own function - usually, `alphasort()` or `versionsort()`, or `NULL` (no sorting) will do, fortunately...)

Comment: The compare function is used to sort an array of pointers (to direntries) ; which is cheape than sorting the dirents themselves, especially because these can differ in size.

Comment: @joop Yes, the comparison function is *used* to sort an array of pointers, but it does not itself sort the array of pointers - hence my question.